# Docker PHP - PECL install fail to detect system type when using heredoc and bash but works with shell set using SHELL command

Tags: php, docker, shell, dockerfile, pecl

I have this simple `Dockerfile-fail` file

```
$ cat Dockerfile-fail                                                                      
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM php:8.1.11-fpm-buster

RUN <<"EOT" bash
  echo $SHELL
  pecl install imagick
  exit 1
EOT
```

And I try to build it like this:

```
$ docker buildx build --no-cache --progress=plain --tag heredoc:test . --file Dockerfile-fail
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-fail
#1 transferring dockerfile: 166B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1
#3 DONE 2.3s

#4 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:d2d74ff22a0e47b21f4bbde337e2ac4cd0a02a2226ef79264878db3dc7e87df8
#4 CACHED

#5 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-fail
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [internal] load .dockerignore
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.1.11-fpm-buster
#7 DONE 0.9s

#8 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.1.11-fpm-buster@sha256:69f7d34281d9338a24ed84d611c8cdfdc058e86ce9873626210338ea369c16a0
#8 CACHED

#9 [2/2] RUN <<"EOT" bash
#9 0.270 /bin/bash
#9 3.934 downloading imagick-3.7.0.tgz ...
#9 3.934 Starting to download imagick-3.7.0.tgz (360,138 bytes)
#9 4.033 .........................................................................done: 360,138 bytes
#9 4.607 33 source files, building
#9 4.607 running: phpize
#9 4.621 Configuring for:
#9 4.621 PHP Api Version:         20210902
#9 4.621 Zend Module Api No:      20210902
#9 4.621 Zend Extension Api No:   420210902
#9 5.168 Please provide the prefix of ImageMagick installation [autodetect] : building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserAO7GZc/imagick-3.7.0
#9 5.168 running: /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-imagick=exit 1
#9 5.234 configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
#9 5.282 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#9 5.284 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#9 5.288 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#9 5.307 checking for 1-pkg-config... no
#9 5.307 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#9 5.308 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
#9 5.309 checking for 1-cc... no
#9 5.309 checking for 1-gcc... no
#9 5.309 checking for cc... cc
#9 5.358 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#9 5.358 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#9 5.385 checking for suffix of executables...
#9 5.415 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#9 5.432 checking for suffix of object files... o
#9 5.448 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#9 5.464 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#9 5.488 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#9 5.508 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#9 5.532 checking for icc... no
#9 5.538 checking for suncc... no
#9 5.539 checking for system library directory... lib
#9 5.567 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#9 5.577 checking build system type... Invalid configuration `1': machine `1-unknown' not recognized
#9 5.578 configure: error: /bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/build/config.sub 1 failed
#9 5.603 ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-imagick=exit 1' failed
#9 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c <<"EOT" bash
  echo $SHELL
  pecl install imagick
  exit 1
EOT]: exit code: 1
------
 > [2/2] RUN <<"EOT" bash:
#9 5.464 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#9 5.488 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#9 5.508 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#9 5.532 checking for icc... no
#9 5.538 checking for suncc... no
#9 5.539 checking for system library directory... lib
#9 5.567 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#9 5.577 checking build system type... Invalid configuration `1': machine `1-unknown' not recognized
#9 5.578 configure: error: /bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/build/config.sub 1 failed
#9 5.603 ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-imagick=exit 1' failed
------
error: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c <<"EOT" bash
  echo $SHELL
  pecl install imagick
  exit 1
EOT]: exit code: 1
```

This fails on detecting system type before compiling and installing php module:

```
#9 5.577 checking build system type... Invalid configuration `1': machine `1-unknown' not recognized
#9 5.578 configure: error: /bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/build/config.sub 1 failed
```

But now I have this very similar file with shell set using `SHELL` command in dockerfile:

```
$ cat Dockerfile-ok                                                                        
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM php:8.1.11-fpm-buster

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-ce"]

RUN <<"EOT"
  echo $SHELL
  pecl install imagick
  exit 1
EOT
```

And now it magically works (failure is normal because there are missing libs):

```
$ docker buildx build --no-cache --progress=plain --tag heredoc:test . --file Dockerfile-ok  
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-ok
#1 transferring dockerfile: 189B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1
#3 DONE 0.8s

#4 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:d2d74ff22a0e47b21f4bbde337e2ac4cd0a02a2226ef79264878db3dc7e87df8
#4 CACHED

#5 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-ok
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [internal] load .dockerignore
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.1.11-fpm-buster
#7 DONE 0.6s

#8 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.1.11-fpm-buster@sha256:69f7d34281d9338a24ed84d611c8cdfdc058e86ce9873626210338ea369c16a0
#8 CACHED

#9 [2/2] RUN <<"EOT" (echo $SHELL...)
#9 0.278 /bin/bash
#9 4.788 downloading imagick-3.7.0.tgz ...
#9 4.788 Starting to download imagick-3.7.0.tgz (360,138 bytes)
#9 4.891 .........................................................................done: 360,138 bytes
#9 5.480 33 source files, building
#9 5.480 running: phpize
#9 5.492 Configuring for:
#9 5.492 PHP Api Version:         20210902
#9 5.492 Zend Module Api No:      20210902
#9 5.492 Zend Extension Api No:   420210902
#9 5.955 Please provide the prefix of ImageMagick installation [autodetect] : building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserApbMiO/imagick-3.7.0
#9 5.956 running: /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-imagick
#9 6.044 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#9 6.045 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#9 6.049 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#9 6.060 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#9 6.061 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
#9 6.062 checking for cc... cc
#9 6.111 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#9 6.111 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#9 6.137 checking for suffix of executables...
#9 6.168 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#9 6.186 checking for suffix of object files... o
#9 6.202 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#9 6.218 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#9 6.243 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#9 6.263 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#9 6.286 checking for icc... no
#9 6.293 checking for suncc... no
#9 6.294 checking for system library directory... lib
#9 6.324 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#9 6.367 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#9 6.367 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#9 6.367 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#9 6.395 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
#9 6.395 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
#9 6.396 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902
#9 6.396 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#9 6.407 checking if debug is enabled... no
#9 6.420 checking if zts is enabled... no
#9 6.421 checking for gawk... no
#9 6.421 checking for nawk... nawk
#9 6.423 checking if nawk is broken... no
#9 6.423 checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
#9 6.426 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#9 6.426 checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... checking Testing /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.426 checking Testing /usr/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.426 checking Testing /usr/sbin/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.427 checking Testing /opt/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.427 checking Testing /opt/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.427 checking Testing /opt/homebrew/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.428 configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.
#9 6.454 ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-imagick' failed
#9 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/bash -ce   echo $SHELL
  pecl install imagick
  exit 1
]: exit code: 1
------
 > [2/2] RUN <<"EOT" (echo $SHELL...):
#9 6.423 checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
#9 6.426 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#9 6.426 checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... checking Testing /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.426 checking Testing /usr/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.426 checking Testing /usr/sbin/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.427 checking Testing /opt/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.427 checking Testing /opt/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.427 checking Testing /opt/homebrew/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
#9 6.428 configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.
#9 6.454 ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-imagick' failed
------
error: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/bash -ce   echo $SHELL
  pecl install imagick
  exit 1
]: exit code: 1
```

It detects system type

```
#9 6.367 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#9 6.367 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#9 6.367 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Why system detection is failing for heredoc + bash in same dockerfile command and works when using `SHELL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the diff of your logs:

[image: log diff]

one difference caught my eye: `--with-imagick=exit 1` vs. `--with-imagick`.

It seems that the `exit 1` gets "inserted" from the `Dockerfile-fail` and causes the differences in the logs (e.g. it adds `checking for *1*-pkg-config... no`) and the problem detecting system type.

There are various ways around this:

1. Remove the `bash` after `"EOT"` (then the [default shell `/bin/sh`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) is used) - there is no need to chose bash over the default sh.
2. Remove the `exit 1` from your `Dockerfile-fail` - the shell exits automatically after the command has executed.
3. Specify the non-default shell [via shebang header](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#example-running-a-multi-line-script) instead of redirecting the heredoc to `bash`:

   ```
   RUN <<"EOT"
   #!/bin/bash
   echo $SHELL
   pecl install imagick
   exit 1
   EOT
   ```

Options 1. and 2. can be combined for a simpler and working Dockerfile.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks. Approved your answer. This explains what is going on mostly. Do you have any clue on why exactly this `exit 1` is inserted in same line as `pecl` command? It is in new line so it should be executed as separate command, right?

Comment: My guess is that the `phpize` / `autotools` / `configure` commands running as part of `pecl install imagick` somehow interpret the `exit 1` (that is passed to `bash` as stdin) as additional argument. Not sure though where exactly this happens and how to find this out.

Comment: I've created [an issue](https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/584) in imagick repo to maybe try to debug this further but this was not very helpful...

Comment: @piotrekkr I find the issue helpful insofar as it supports the suggestion to just '1. Remove the bash after "EOT"' (and the '2. Remove the exit 1') thus getting a clean and working Dockerfile. I also completely understand the Imagick maintainer not wanting to spend time analyzing a problem caused by "doing multiline RUN commands wrong". You might consider creating another issue in the place that suggested doing 'RUN <<"EOT" bash' (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#here-documents ?) referencing your problem here.

Comment: I've created [issue in docker buildkit repo](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/3641) and I've got and explanation of this behavior. `By writing <<EOF bash, the entire heredoc is fed to bash's stdin, so the line exit 1 is read into imagemagick. This doesn't happen for the shebang case, since the entire file is written first, and it doesn't happen for the empty case because the whole script is run directly through the shell as a "fake-heredoc".`